# String position multiply with array position

Tags: c++

Something wrong with my code, I want to multiply a string of numbers with an array of numbers(same length) and store the product in variable product, then I want to store this product of each column in my string variable (as a new values)

```
string var1 = "1232253759";
int arr[] = {5,3,7,1,2,8,9,2,2,1};
for(int i = 0; i < var1.size(); i++)
{
  for(int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
  {
     int product = 0;
     product = var1[i] * arr[n];
     var1[i] = product;
   }
}
```

there is a short output of this result:
245
-33
-231
25
50
400
-1008
32

Comment: Try `product = (var1[i] - '0') * arr[n];` (and then also `var1[i] = product + '0';`)

Comment: What result do you expect? Start with a string of length two.

Comment: @n.m. new values of var = "5, 6, 21, 2..., 9", I want to multiply first element of var1 with first element of arr and so on

Comment: What do you mean by `"5, 6, 21, 2..., 9"`? Is it a string? Does it contain actual comma characters and spaces? If so, it's about three times as long as the original string,  possibly more because 7*3=21 (two chars).

Comment: @n.m. Take first element from the string (it's 1), take first element of arr( it's 5), do 1*5 = 5, replace this 5 with the first element of var1 ( that is 1, so 1, will be replaced with 5)

Comment: Ive updated my answer let me know @lidya_q

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] before asking here. Without this, your question is considered off-topic. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please don't tell me what to do. *Tell me what result you want to see*. You have a string `"45"` and an array `{7,8}`.  Your result should be `"..."` (replace the ellipsis with specific digits).

Answer (score 1):

So if im not mistaken this is what you want right.
where totalProduct will hold the product of every product and arr2 holds your columns. I added resultAsString so you have the result as string

note the `var.at(i)-'0'` which does the convertion you want or i think you are looking for.

for the conversion from int to string im using

```
std::stringstream ss;
      ss << product;
```

a less C++ aproach would have been the atoi(product) function. or if using c++ 11 std:to_string(product)
Hope it helps

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>



int main() {
  std::string var1 = "1232253759";
  int arr[] = {5,3,7,1,2,8,9,2,2,1};
  int arr2[var1.size()];
  int totalProduct = 0;
  std::string resultAsString = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < var1.size(); i++)
  {
    // for(int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
    // {

      int product = (var1.at(i)-'0') * arr[i];
      // std::cout << product << "\n";
      arr2[i] = product;
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << product;
      resultAsString += ss.str();
      totalProduct += product;
     //}
  }
  // for (int i = var1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
  //   std::cout << arr2[i] << " ";
  std::cout << resultAsString;
}
```

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, you right, I printout product, and it's always one value

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: that's the printout of your code :
(

Comment: Uhm, I just copy paste your code and I executed, and it printed only : " ( ", <- this

Comment: @lidya_q sorry man you were right. Edited. its been a long time :P

Comment: @jstuartnilme , Ok thank you "Man" :), it's printed as needs, I will make some changes to get the right result. Thx for your help, and thanks ofr others who tried to help

Comment: Care to upvote :). Great it worked

Answer (score 0):

`var1[i]` is a `char`, not an `int`. `char` implicitly cast to `int` and calculation goes wrong. You need to map `char` with number to number itself ('1' -> 1, '2' -> 2). To do it subtract value of '0'. I.e. `var1[i] - '0'` it's number for char